# Grep within { }

Tags: linux, grep

I have a raw text configuration from a load balancer and want to grep for only the virtual servers that have a TCP profile applied.  A sample config is below, and from this I would just like to output the first line (I can use `awk` later to just filter on the VS name if needed).  Note that I'm doing this offline, without access to the device.

```
ltm virtual /Common/custom_ldap-vs {
    destination /Common/10.1.1.2:389
    ip-protocol tcp
    mask 255.255.255.255
    persist {
        /Common/source_addr {
            default yes
        }
    }
    pool /Common/dev_itim_rhitimdevtds_ldap-pool
    profiles {
       <b> /Common/Custom_tcp_Profile { } </b>
    }
    source 0.0.0.0/0
    source-address-translation {
        type automap
    }
    translate-address enabled
    translate-port enabled
    vlans {
        /Common/vlan_3
    }
    vlans-enabled
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try first stripping the newlines out of the file. Then break out each virtual server into it's own line. Then you can grep for your profile string:

```
perl -pe 's/\n//mg' yourfile.txt | perl -pe 's/ltm virtual/\n/g' | grep Custom_tcp_Profile | perl -pe 's/(.*?){.*/$1/'
```